# How do I escape a slash in AppleScript?

Tags: mac, applescript

How do I escape a slash in AppleScript? The documentation seems to suggest that

> set target_string to "\\"

should return a single `\`, but in fact it returns `\\\\`. On the other hand,

> set target_string to "\"

gives an error. I've tried this on [Mac OS X v10.6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) (Snow Leopard) and older versions of Mac OS X.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what's going on for you, but `set target_string to "\\"` returns a single \ for me on Snow Leopard (10.6.4)

Comment: And progress David?

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to do:

```
set target_string to "\\"
```

Comment: Sorry, oddly enough SU read \\ as an escape in my original question. I've edited it. For some reason, your suggestion doesn't work on for applescript on my computers.

Comment: what happens when you do something like `set target_string to "\\"` then do a `display dialog target_string`.  What you see in the "return" window in Script Editor isn't necessarily what other script objects see, especially true with Strings.

like this: http://peelman.us/skitch/ase-slashes-20100728-114610.png

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your sample code is not working on your system, but this should work too:

```
set target_string to ASCII character (92)
```